How to extract particular string for an URL
I have a URL something like below
https://example.com/abc/A3V5C96RVH3W9JS2TUP?parameters=abc

from the above url I have to extract only "A3V5C96RVH3H9JS1TQP" using regex in javascript.
also "A3V5C96RVH3H9JS1TQP" will be always 19 character in length and will always start from "A" the characters /abc/ can be anything else shouldn't match based on /abc/.
it can be even this
https://example.com/pqrs/A3V5C96WVA3W9JS2TUP?parameters=abc

but only "A3V5C96WVA3W9JS2TUP" has to be extracted.
and if the url comes like below, it shouldn't extract anything.
https://example.com/u/click?_t=A20e1ffb2989453eaf5755b1940a5e02&_m=3983d6e6519b4de899be964096507c96&_e=JCanVuhVZwIxCtu4vrMeoOJkD73_W5aswybJFJ3oCDoAS583vt8rVhUPdMoKy87fF6Ku92ACv9F26yy-evyg0SK0D9ATYKemg0C14JezMrDy3NYAJfTg3FwZe2tmQ5bmqX-zmARM2j3VeWs8Xslv8JDIec4RoXfWbDGZ2akjm3Ws5iLpeYTCi-NgfBCnWHoIQejtPAIXNkyfOVsjmCvZFdZC8ZgaGqX6sMqa9Pe-bDfph3DMoE2zowCsqiEQYrG92Sq8ISkc0hu9HNpqtQ7IpcBSSKf66ZXuSK3uifuv_emnbiBfJD1qtbioQe7ZRKyM3f6cwiifcp4FGGcJVDJFZXWFeKBM_z0bsp12-cX2j81sYlkcQ_WDeLHE_xEJE0BogYMjaE6DbGI77Tdxy2M3dzYXVvCTVhoQkcZ6DTiRF5DA_i6C0WMWX2AfKnCZL3xt_MCXfqf5Vd99H0sr4iJ1GHhpit3DcrRpe18nwBLzi5qCpZ2XCvvbjlPBsCvWm8U7GbmDw7T7etiyuCnPlR299ZpQVLHskMSnnhGkt71fWTlBhOndKv5TKJzpk8iNqksJtrbhUBa9rapjLZbwwciSZeoau0BD1ER0wAUvvHRS-NUr8ySJ5eH6D2NEe3npGaG0GSETarAqnirs3qvUIl6xseZ94AGUk4bnD2wdsQ4LcbsC50JXd7gAEjcEBEMKUFsyZR2zIkB-LWQmGylUxwDlxZU1Z-Kq7MHlfqx9HHaexEq8%3D

Tried some regular expressions without success

If the URL is reasonably stable (e.g., it's always the last part of the path), there is not much of a reason to use regex over simple parsing. Or you can even use a URL parser.

You can use /(A.{19})? and extract the first capturing group assuming the URLs always have parameters (a ? token after what you're trying to retrieve)

the url characters before the id varies from link to link but varies in set of 5 to 6 words, we have a code in place which is extracting using substring, but now we have requirement to change that code and extract the id using regular expressions

@Aaron tried your method, but it breaks when the url is something like the 3rd one in the question. it matches in the middle as well.

Maybe [/=](A.{18})([?&]|$) then ? Matches either the last segment of the path or a parameter (but that'd match any parameter that starts with an A and is 19 char long) ; tried it here : https://regex101.com/r/iws0OA/1

Try this one \/(A.{18}) https://regex101.com/r/qlE8qD/1

"also "A3V5C96RVH3H9JS1TQP" will be always 20 character in length" but A3V5C96RVH3H9JS1TQP is 19 characters. As is A3V5C96WVA3W9JS2TUP

sorry its 19 characters not 20.

Need to match 19 characters, start with 'A' after '/'.
So, use regex:
(?<=\/)(A.{18})

or

/(?<=\/)(A.{18})/gi

Here, I use regex positive lookahead to match first / character.
More details, check: regex positive lookahead
Regex Output: regex101
